# Question on the discriminant of a irreducible polynomial

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions, discriminant

Let $\mathbb{K}_5$ be the field with five elements. I don't know to describe the splitting field of $f(x) = x^{3} + x + 1\in\mathbb{K}[5]$ in terms of a root and the discriminant. Clearly, $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{K}_5$. So far, I know that the field extension $\mathbb{K}[\alpha,\sqrt{\Delta}]$ for a root $\alpha$ and the discriminant $\Delta$ of $f(x)$ is the splitting field of $\mathbb{K}_5$ if $\sqrt{\Delta}\notin\mathbb{K}_5$. On the contrary, $\mathbb{K}_5[\alpha]$ is the splitting field of $\mathbb{K}_5$. How do I determine whether or not $\sqrt{\Delta}\notin\mathbb{K}_5$ in this case?

Comment: What does "let $\mathbb{K}_5$" mean?

Comment: The field with five elements.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to consider the discriminant. If $\alpha$ is a root of $f$, then $E = \mathbb{K}_{5}[\alpha]$ is the field with $5^3$ elements, and every extension of finite fields is known to be Galois, so  $E$ will contain all roots of $f$. Explicitly, they will be $\alpha, \alpha^{5}, \alpha^{25}$

Comment: Why does $E$ contains all roots of $f$ provided $\mathbb{K}_{5}$ is finite?

Comment: Your statements are confusing. $\newcommand{\k}{\mathbb{K}}$
You said that you would like to know how to describe the splitting field of $\k_5$,
but you already know a description $\k_5[\alpha]$.

Comment: $E$ contains all roots of $f$ because $E$ is a normal extension. This means that for any $\alpha\in E$, we have $\beta\in E$ for any conjugate $\beta$ of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{K}_5$.